# Is it normal to have a src/bin directory?

Tags: linux, directory

My current understanding:

bin -> binary files (non-human-readable) EX: .o files

src -> source files (human-readable files) EX: .c files

So then, what would one expect to be in a src/bin directory? Is this inherently contradictory? I ask because a homework assignment mandates this structure, and I am trying to understand it from a more general Unix perspective.

NOTE: the src directory has two sub-directories: src/bin and src/lib

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to have this sort of structure:

```
src
   bin
      main1.c
      main2.c
   lib
      func1.c
      func2.c
```

i.e., `src\bin` would be used to hold the source code for programs,
and `src\lib` would be used to hold the source code for library functions.

Comment: As the point is often missed I wanted to add that `lib` is often considered the correct location for binaries that are not directly invoked by the user.  `hier(7)` and `filesystem-hierarchy(7)` are good resources on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

These could possibly be intermediate staging areas where files are installed when building them.

The binaries are built in `src/bin` and libraries are built in `src/lib`.  When doing the actual installation with `make install` the compiled binaries and libraries are copied from there to wherever it is they are supposed to be installed.

Alternatively (or additionally), the actual source for the binaries may be kept under `src/bin`, and the source for the binaries may be kept under `src/lib`.

On OpenBSD, for example, [the base system sources are kept in `/usr/src`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/) which has subdirectories `bin` (for utilities that will go into `/bin`), `usr.bin` (for utilities that will go into `/usr/bin`), `lib` etc.

In this case though, intermediate binaries are built in `/usr/obj` (in corresponding subdirectories), to keep the object files separated from the source files.